# significant amount of size difference after loading two exact same dump files

Tags: svn, repository, svndump

We are exporting a dump file from a path in a remote svn repository.
Generally speaking the size of a dump file should be bigger than the original repo files.

With the exact same steps and commands in CMD , my colleague and I get different results.

The size of our dump files are the same but when we try to load it onto our local machine and then do the checkout , we get a significant amount of difference in the size of the local repo.

The size of the dump file : 5.8 GB
The size of my local repo after loading the dump file : 8 GB
The size of my colleague's local repo after loading the dump file : 2.3 GB

Why is that so?

I paid attention to the number of the revisions but Surprisingly , the numbers in both cases are the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible reasons why the repositories differ ~x2 in size after being loaded from the same dump file:

1. Different versions of the `svnadmin` tool used to create a new repository to load the repository dump into.
2. Different options used when running `svnadmin create`.
3. Consequence of points 1 and 2: different formats and settings of a repository.

You should add exact commands and versions of the Subversion command-line tools used by you and your colleague to your question. You can run `svnadmin --version` to find out the version.